# Swapping Two Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose we have the following problem:

$$\sum_{d=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^d f(s)g(d)$$

where $f$ and $g$  are two arbitrary function. If I want to sum over $s$ first and then $d$ what changes do I have to make? Is it enough to do

$$\sum_{s=0}^{\infty} \sum_{d=0}^{\infty} f(s)g(d)$$

I feel as if we would be missing something if we do this. Is this correct or do we need to add in a factor to keep track of how many times each pair $(s,d)$ occurs?

Comment: @turkeyhundt: I don't believe you, can you prove it?

Comment: @turkeyhundt: Are you claiming that $\sum_{t=1}^3 \sum_{x=0}^t (x+t) = \sum_{x=0}^3 \sum_{t=1}^3 (x+t)$. Because that is not true.

Comment: holy cow, i misread the problem.  i'm dumb.  I'll see myself out now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct interchange is

$$\sum_{d=0}^\infty\sum_{s=0}^d=\sum_{s=0}^\infty\sum_{d=s}^\infty$$

The key is, $s$ is never greater than $d$.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was forgetting something but wasn't sure what.