# swap $\sum_k^\infty\sum_j^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to simplify an expression by using the binomial theorem, but I am afraid I am taking wrong assumptions: when are we allowed to make the following claim:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} c_k  a_{j,k}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_j
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
b_j=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{j,k}
\end{equation}
provided that $b_j$ exists. Is this always true?

In my case, I am looking at the following series, but my question is aimed at a more general setting. Am I allowed to write:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a^k{ {k-1} \choose {j} }\langle d^j\rangle x^{k-1-j}\doteq  \sum_j^\infty \langle d^j\rangle\frac{1}{(x-a)^{j+1}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Shouldn't that be $b_j=\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty c_k a_{j,k}$ ? This is because $j.k$ ranges over all pairs of integers with $0\le j<k$.

Comment: I don't see it, perhaps could you expand your comment in an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: I won't write an answer because the question is basically a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1636638/362967) and probably [others](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052375/362967). The first pair of sums takes any value of $k\ge1$ and then any value of $j$ in the range $\{0,...,,k-1\}$. So that is exactly every pair of integers satisfying $0\le j<k<\infty$. If you pick $j$ first, which can take any value from $0$ up, your choice of $k$ is restricted by $j<k$ so can take any value from $j+1$ up.

Comment: Yes now I understand! Thank you very much! Should I delete my question or mark it as dupplicate? The link you sent is exactly the answer I was looking for.